# Using react redirect component in custom class

Tags: reactjs

I want to redirect to a URL `/login` using a custom class as in following example, but it won't work. Here's my code:

```
// Auth.js
import React from 'react';
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
class Auth {
    isUserLoggedIn() { ... }
    login() {
        return <Redirect to="/login" />
    }
}
export default new Auth();
```

I am calling `login()` from a redux-thunk action maker as I want to keep a user session check before I can hit server API. The code as under:

```
import Auth from './Auth';
export const profileFetchAction = (data) => {
    if(!Auth.isUserLoggedIn()) {
        return Auth.login();
    }
    return (dispatch) => {
        return axios.post('http://api.url/profile') ...
    }
    // ... 
}
```

I compiles good, but won't redirect. How can I do this?

Comment: Just remove `return` from `return Auth.login();` and this should work.

Comment: @ravibagul91 no luck...

Comment: try the else part also.

Comment: @ravibagul91 no luck...